# highcharts - 2 date picker questions

Tags: javascript, highcharts

1) I am wondering how I can remove the date picker from the right side of the chart?  I really only need the left rangeSelector buttons i.e. 24 hours, 6 hours...

2) is there anyway to turn off the dataLabels when you click on one of the rangeSelector options as well?

When zoomed in to show 5 minutes worth of data the dataLabels are handy, but when looking at 24 hours worth they make the chart quite unusable due to crowding. It would be nice if they could be automagically turned off when I zoomed out.

Huge thanks for your help, if this is indeed possible.

---

For the second option, i'm looking to toggle the visibility of

```
   plotOptions:{series: {
      dataLabels:{
            enabled:true,
```

Comment: `rangeSelector : { inputEnabled:false },` will disable datepicker. For second question please provide some code sample(jsfiddle)

Comment: Much thanks, but I do want the left side range selector buttons, such as 24 hours, 6 hours, 5 minutes

But I do not want the right side February 11 to 11 date picker option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/deep3015/qp7z0pk1/2/)

After customization of range selector from [Highstock Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/lazy-loading/)

```
/**
* Load new data depending on the selected min and max
 */
function afterSetExtremes(e) {

    var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];

    chart.showLoading('Loading data from server...');
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/from-sql.php?start=' + Math.round(e.min) +
            '&end=' + Math.round(e.max) + '&callback=?', function (data) {

        chart.series[0].setData(data);
        chart.hideLoading();
    });
}

// See source code from the JSONP handler at https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/from-sql.php
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/from-sql.php?callback=?', function (data) {

    // Add a null value for the end date
    data = [].concat(data, [[Date.UTC(2011, 9, 14, 19, 59), null, null, null, null]]);

    // create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'candlestick',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        navigator: {
            adaptToUpdatedData: false,
            series: {
                data: data
            }
        },

        scrollbar: {
            liveRedraw: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL history by the minute from 1998 to 2011'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Displaying 1.7 million data points in Highcharts Stock by async server loading'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            buttons: [{     //customization of buttons
                type: 'hour',
                count: 24,
                text: '24h'
            }, {
                type: 'hour',
                count: 6,
                text: '6h'
            }, {
                type: 'minute',
                count: 5,
                text: '5m'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false, // it remove datepicker
        },

        xAxis: {
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: afterSetExtremes,
                setExtremes: function(e) {
                    if(typeof(e.rangeSelectorButton)!== 'undefined')
                    {
                      if(e.rangeSelectorButton.text=='5m'){
                            addlables(); //function to add data label
                      }else{
                            removelables(); // function to remove data lable
                      }
                    }
                }
            },
            minRange: 300 * 1000 // 5min * 1000
        },

        yAxis: {
            floor: 0
        },
        plotOptions:{
        series: {
            dataLabels:{
            enabled:false,
            }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: data,
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
});

function removelables(){
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var opt = chart.series[0].options;
        opt.dataLabels.enabled = false;
        chart.series[0].update(opt);
}
function addlables(){
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var opt = chart.series[0].options;
        opt.dataLabels.enabled = true;
        chart.series[0].update(opt);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response - I believe that's exactly what I am looking for!  Huge thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it helped.Mark it as accepted answer by clicking tick mark at top left where answer starts